# Deixar função rodando em loop até a aplicação fechar

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Tenho o seguinte codigo que fica trocando de imagem de tempo em tempos.

```
if Timer1.enabled = true then
begin
 Gauge1.Progress := Gauge1.Progress +1;
   if Gauge1.Progress=10 then
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\2.jpg');

   if Gauge1.Progress=30 then
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\3.jpg');

   if Gauge1.Progress=50 then
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\1.jpg');
 end;
```

Como faço pra que fique rodando em loop até que a aplicação seja finalizada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá esclarecer a sua dúvida... Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira. Dado que você já tenha incluído um componente do tipo Timer na tela chamado Timer1.

1º - Crie um evento OnTimer do componente Timer.

2º - Coloque o código, ficando parecido como este.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin    
    Gauge1.Progress := Gauge1.Progress + 1;

    if Gauge1.Progress = 10 then
        Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\2.jpg')    
    else if Gauge1.Progress = 30 then
        Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\3.jpg')    
    else if Gauge1.Progress = 50 then
        Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\1.jpg');    
end;
```

3º - Defina o tempo em que o *Gauge1.Progress* será incrementado, em Timer1 na propriedade *Interval*, lembrando que o tempo é medido em ms, ou seja, 1000 é 1 segundo. Caso seja 1 segundo o tempo definido, em 10 segundos o processo trocará a imagem para a 2.jpg, em 30 segundos 3.jpg e assim por diante.

4º - Quando você quiser iniciar essa contagem basta colocar a propriedade Enabled do Timer1 em True, e caso contrário False.

5º - Neste caso a partir de 50 a imagem sempre será a 1.jpg, digamos que quando o *Gauge1.Progress* chegar em 60 vamos querer iniciar a contagem novamente do 0. Então trocamos o código e colocamos algo assim:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin    
    Gauge1.Progress := Gauge1.Progress + 1;

    if Gauge1.Progress = 10 then
        Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\2.jpg')    
    else if Gauge1.Progress = 30 then
        Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\3.jpg')    
    else if Gauge1.Progress = 50 then
        Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\1.jpg')
    else if Gauge1.Progress = 60 then
        Gauge1.Progress = 0;     
end;
```

6º - Caso o *Gauge1.Progress* não possa ser zerado, dependendo da lógica do seu programa, então crie uma variável no Form do tipo Integer para fazer este processo. Ficando algo como:

```
private 
    contador: Integer;
...
...
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin    
    Gauge1.Progress := Gauge1.Progress + 1;
    Inc(contador);

    if contador = 10 then
        Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\2.jpg')    
    else if contador = 30 then
        Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\3.jpg')    
    else if contador = 50 then
        Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\1.jpg')
    else if contador = 60 then
        contador = 0;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use uma estrutura de repetição par isto, vamos tentar com `while`:

```
while Gauge1.Progress < 100 do
begin
  if (Gauge1.Progress = 10) then
  begin
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\2.jpg');
  end
  else if (Gauge1.Progress = 30) then
  begin
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\3.jpg');
  end
  else if (Gauge1.Progress = 50) then
  begin
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\1.jpg');
  end;
  Inc(Gauge1.Progress);
end;
```

Ou seja enquanto a % não chegar a 100% você vai atualizando, agora você precisa encaixar essa estrutura de forma quem não pare seu sistema para executar ela! Isso já depende de quando você vai rodar essa implementação da `Gauge`.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, basicamente pode usar o TTimmer, coloque no evento dele: onTimer,e defina o Interval para o tempo que achar necessaríssimo.

Comment: não preciso usar uma tgauge para controlar?, se puder ser um pouco mais especifico

Comment: Não o Timmer ja tem um loop, o onTimer

Comment: pode editar sua pergunta e colocar um exemplo de como ficaria?

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if Timer1.enabled = true then
    begin
        Gauge1.Progress := Gauge1.Progress +1;
        if Gauge1.Progress=10 then
            Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\2.jpg');

        if Gauge1.Progress=30 then
            Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\3.jpg');

        if Gauge1.Progress=50 then
            Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\contas_a_pagar\img\home\1.jpg');
    end;
end;
```

na propriedade Interval você define o tempo do loop em milessegundos.
Timer1.interval := 1000; //1 segundo

Comment: Você simplesmente copiou meu código e não me auxiliou em nada.

Comment: Se olhar bem na primeira linha eu coloquei no evento onTimer, e na ultima linha expiquei como funciona o componente Timer.